# Specify profile for dependency with 'provided' scope in Maven

Tags: maven

I am developing a multi-module build that requires one of the artifacts produced by another module in the build as a dependency when I run integration tests for the build. I am using the 'provided' scope so it is not included in the artifact produced for the module we are building for, but to insure that it is compiled so we can pick it up for our tests. However, the component we are listing as a dependency has its own set of integration tests that it runs. I would like to be able to specify in the definition of the dependency the profile Maven should use when resolving the dependency (e.g., package, and not verify). Is there a way to specify in the definition of the dependency which Maven phase / profile we want to resolve the dependency with?

The current setup:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

The desired setup:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>version</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <!-- only go up until package phase for dependency artifact --> 
        <phase>package</phase>
        <!-- use dependency's skip-tests profile to compile it -->
        <profile>skip-tests</profile>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you please provide or re-phase your question? Maybe adding an ascii diagram of the multi-module structure and dependencies? Otherwise your requirement may lead to misunderstanding (that is, I didn't get it)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that B is the dependency, A the project you want to build with full tests, and C the parent of A and B.

A depends on B, with this inside its pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>BgroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>BartifactId</artifactId>
        <version>Bversion</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

B has a no-test profile, not active by default. It is defined at the end of its pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>no-test</id>
      <active>false</active>
      <build>
       <plugins>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
           <skipTests>true</skipTests>
         </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
     </build>        
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you can build C with the no-test profile. You must execute the following command at the root of C project:

```
mvn clean install -Pno-test
```

As a result, C will build B first (because A needs B) with the no-test profile. So B will be built with the "skip-tests" property.

Then C will build A. As no specific behaviour is defined in the pom of A project for the "no-test" profile, A will be build with full tests.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Would the profile you specified be in the pom for the module I am provided tests for (let's call this module Module A), or the module that I list as a dependency (Module B)? I want to the build for Module A with the 'all-tests' profile (which runs all tests, including unit, component, integration tests), and uses Module B's artifact as a dependency. If I put this dependency in the 'all-tests' profile Module A, how does it know what profile to use for Module B? I'm going to test this proposed solution, but am wondering how your solution works.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question (I read again). So if I rephrase, you want to use the jar produced after the B package phase as dependency for A ? Sorry if I make you repeat...

Comment: No worries; it's kind of a complicated issue. I want to use Module B's artifact as a dependency with provided scope in Module A. When I currently run the build for Module A with Module B listed as a dependency, it runs the entire build for Module B, including Module B's integration tests, component tests, and unit tests. When I specify Module B as a dependency, I want to skip all of the tests for Module B, and just compile it. I want to see if there's a way in the dependency definition to specify what profile to use for Module B.

Comment: Could you provide the pom of A ? It may sound as a stupid question, but is B a child of A ?

Comment: B is not a child of A. A and B are modules in a multi-module Maven project. B's artifact is needed to run integration tests for A. I am not allowed to post the source code online unfortunately, which is why I am using an abstract example.

Comment: Ok thanks. When you define a maven dependency, it is not built again, it is resolved as the corresponding artifact in your .m2 repository. So when you tell that building A triggers the built of B, I am under the impression that you actually build C (the parent of A and B), and that triggers B with full tests, then A with full tests. If I am right, you can have the build you want be defining the profile inside B and running the command on C. I update my answer to explain, I hope that might help you.